# Given two points and asked to find an exponential function described by $y=ab^x$, how to show that the function is unique?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The exponential function had to go through the points $P(0,1)$ and $Q(1,2)$.

I found the function to be $y=2^x$.

How can I show that this is the only such exponential function.

Comment: Did you mean $a \cdot b^x$ in the title?

Comment: @dxiv yes, sorry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume there is an other function of the form $f(x)=ab^x$.

then

$f(0)=a=1$

and

$f(1)=ab=b=2$

thus

$2^x$ is the unique one.